# How do I stop a fixed sidebar from overlapping the footer with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

**Note:** The ["duplicate" linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062163/how-to-make-a-sidebar-sticky-when-scrolling-between-header-and-footer-with-jquer) is another post of mine (inadvertently posted twice). I've already flagged the duplicates for removal.

I need a strictly jQuery solution for this problem. This is because I'm using Wordpress and the sidebar widget that I want to make sticky is inside an `<aside>` element which I cannot make full height.

In the same way that `.scrollTop()` detects how far down the page I am to make the sidebar widget sticky I need JS detect how far up I am from the bottom of the page to "unstick" the widget via assigning a new fixed position.

I tried to to this with `.offset()` but I have been unable to make it work so far.

```
  function stopDiv() {
    var distance = $('.footer').offset().top - $('.widget').offset().top;
    if (distance < 10) {
      $('.widget').css({
        'top': 'auto',
        'bottom': '10px'
      });
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the snippet below my sidebar scrolls as it should, but I want the sidebar to assume a new fixed position when I reach <10px distance from the footer.

I want the sidebar to assume a new fixed position above the footer until the user scrolls back up.

```js
  // Fixed Widget
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('.widget');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 380)
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px',
        'right': '30px'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto',
        'right': 'auto'
      });
  }
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();

/* My attempt 
  function stopDiv() {
    var distance = $('.footer').offset().top - $('.widget').offset().top;
    if (distance < 10) {
      $('.widget').css({
        'top': 'auto',
        'bottom': '10px'
      });
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(stopDiv);
  stopDiv();
  */
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 85%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "main main main sidebar";
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #266392;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
}

.nav h1 {
  place-self: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.nav i {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 98%;
  justify-self: start;
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e8624c;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  height: 900px;
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: #209B66;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-column: 4;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container>p {
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.widget {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #E3962F;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1>Sticky Sidebar Problem</h1>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>
        [Main Content]
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <p>[Sidebar Container]</p>

      <div class="widget">
        <p> [Widget]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: State the question clearly. What is your question?

Comment: Post title reworded.

Comment: Set the maximum `z-index` value to the footer which will cause the side bar to flow under the footer

Comment: I see that I need to clarify more. The JS above causes the sidebar to become fixed when you scroll down using scrollTop(). What I want is for the sidebar to become unfixed before reaching the footer _without_ snapping back up to the top initial position. Does that make sense? Its a lot to describe.

Comment: At which position you want to unfix the sidebar?

Comment: I guess I want it to perform similarly to this https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/. Though, I'm hoping to modify the code I have here rather than have to use this method. What do you think is best?

Comment: Seems like a best approach. For this you will need to write javadcript even for remove sticky. If you looking for the same, I will be able to help you

Comment: Yes sir, that's what I'm hoping to accomplish. I'd like to do that by appending the code I currently have.

Comment: @ramesh I just reworded the post. I didn't start off very well. Still learning how to write good posts :)

Comment: You seems like a fast learner. Good luck for your future :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make a sidebar sticky when scrolling between header and footer with jQuery (without scrolling over them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062163/how-make-a-sidebar-sticky-when-scrolling-between-header-and-footer-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This correct answer was provided by [benvc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9958942/benvc) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062163/how-to-make-a-sidebar-sticky-when-scrolling-between-header-and-footer-with-jquer). Sorry for the duplicate. I wanted to post the answer here in case anyone landed on this page rather than the other.

> ...below is a jquery solution using your code with new jquery for the sticky sidebar widget and css to make the sidebar widget position: absolute and right: 30px (that value is arbitrary depending on where exactly you want the widget to sit inside the sidebar). Also, commented out a few other css lines that either weren't doing anything or interfered with the responsiveness of your grid layout (sticky sidebar functionality works with or without those changes, although you may need to adjust the right css of your widget element, including media queries, depending on where your layout ultimately ends up).

```js
$(function() {

  const sidebar = $('.sidebar-container');
  const widget = $('.widget');
  const footer = $('.footer');
  const space = 10; // arbitrary value to create space between the window and widget
  const startTop = sidebar.offset().top + 60; // arbitrary start top position
  const endTop = footer.offset().top - widget.height() - space;
  
  widget.css('top', startTop);
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  
    let windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    let widgetTop = widget.offset().top;
    let newTop = startTop;
  
    if (widgetTop >= startTop && widgetTop <= endTop) {
      if (windowTop > startTop - space && windowTop < endTop - space) {
        newTop = windowTop + space;
      } else if (windowTop > endTop - space) {
        newTop = endTop;
      }
      widget.stop().animate({
        'top': newTop
      });
    }
  
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 85%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "main main main sidebar";
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #266392;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
}

.nav h1 {
  place-self: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.nav i {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main {
  height: 1500px;
  /*width: 98%;
  justify-self: start;*/
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 10px;
  /*float: left;*/
  background-color: #e8624c;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  height: 900px;
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: #209B66;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-column: 4;
  /*top: 10px;*/
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container>p {
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.widget {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #E3962F;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1>Sticky Sidebar Problem</h1>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>
        [Main Content]
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <p>[Sidebar Container]</p>

      <div class="widget">
        <p> [Widget]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```