# How do I make a Wordpress sidebar widget behave like it has position:sticky with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Since I'm working in Wordpress my sidebar is an  element. This means it cannot be `height: 100%` without making it `position: absolute` which will break my CSS grid.

How can I make the sidebar behave like it's in `position: sticky` by scrolling down with the user but stopping at the footer using jQuery/JS alone?

```js
  // Fixed Widget
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('.widget');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 380)
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px',
        'right': '30px'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto',
        'right': 'auto'
      });
  }
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();

  function stopDiv() {
    var distance = $('.footer').offset().top - $('.widget').offset().top;
    if (distance < 10) {
      $('.widget').css({
        'top': 'auto',
        'bottom': '10px'
      });
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(stopDiv);
  stopDiv();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 85%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "main main main sidebar";
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #266392;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
}

.nav h1 {
  place-self: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.nav i {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 98%;
  justify-self: start;
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e8624c;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  height: 900px;
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: #209B66;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-column: 4;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.sidebar-container>p {
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.widget {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #E3962F;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1>Sticky Sidebar Problem</h1>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>
        [Main Content]
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <p>[Sidebar Container]</p>

      <div class="widget">
        <p> [Widget]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

This post is mostly code so I have to write some stuff so that it will let me post this edit so here is the text that I am writing so that I can just save and move on with my life please ignore this omg how much more do I have to type. Is this enough? How about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make a sidebar sticky when scrolling between header and footer with jQuery (without scrolling over them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062163/how-make-a-sidebar-sticky-when-scrolling-between-header-and-footer-with-jquery)